# jquery global ajaxError handler invoked, even if mvc Ajax.ActionLink call is cancelled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a jquery global handler registered in the layout page to handle common errors in entire site. Here is how it is registered in the Layout Page.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    if (jqXHR.status == "610") {
        window.location.replace(loginUrl);
    }
    else if (jqXHR.status == "600") { }
    else {
        alert("An error occurred processing your request");
    }
});
```

I have an Ajax.ActionLink in one of my view(cshtml) which I am cancelling using the **OnBegin** handler by returning false from the handler as given below

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Save List", "_SaveStates",null, 
                                   new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSaveSuccess",
                                                     OnBegin = "onSaveBegin",
                                                     OnComplete = "onComplete"
                                   }, 
                                   new {@class="t-button", id="lnkSaveList" })

function onSaveBegin() {
    var grid = $('#tlkBulkAddGrid').data('tGrid');
    if (grid.total == undefined || grid.total == "" || grid.total < 1) {
        alert('List is Empty');
        return false; //Return False to cancel ajax call
    }
    $('.t-status .t-icon').addClass('t-loading');
}
```

The strange part is that even if I **return false** from the **onSaveBegin()** the global **ajaxError** gets invoked. I don't understand why the global error handler should be triggered, because the ajax call has been cancelled and no request made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning *false* from the `OnBegin` method of the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper is practically returning *false* from the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `beforeSend` function.

jQuery documentation:

> Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request.

Canceling a request leads to throwing an ajax error and invoking your handler.

To solve your issue you can check for `thrownError` parameter inside the function:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    if (thrownError === 'canceled' || thrownError === 'abort')
        return;
    ...
});
```

Comment: As of jquery 1.5, the thrownError is 'abort', instead of 'canceled', but your explanation is correct. If I am correct, please edit your answer by replacing 'canceled' by 'abort'. That way I will be able to accept your answer as solution.

Comment: @Nirvan, the method is called `abort`, `thrownError` parameter is `canceled` though. Tested on `jQuery 1.8.2` and `jQuery 1.10.2`.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your above comment. In my case thrownError === 'canceled' is returning false, but thrownError === 'abort' is returning true. I am using MVC 3 and exact jquery version jquery-1.5.1.